# Horrendous performance in After Effects

Tags: after-effects

Some 20 years ago I used BSPlayer and some other audio players. They came with visualizations that displayed audio histogram in a variety of shapes and forms. It all worked in real time, for stereo, simultaneously with the audio playback, and only used a small fraction of the CPU cycles (about 5%).

Fast forward 20 years, I am rendering the same thing in After Effects. It is a very simplistic audio histogram visualization, in mono, in monochrome, about 300x300 pixels. And this renders at 1/5 real time, using 100% of only 1 CPU core (because Adobe did not bother to implement SMP).

Over the 20 year that've passed, the CPUs have allegedly grown in performance about 100-1000 times, let's say 500 on average, depending on what you consider. So, what factors limit After Effects to 1/50,000 of the performance of the olden days' BSPlayer visualization?